# rotating one object according to point

Tags: c, math, opengl, graphics

```
                  O
                 position 2



 O                             Y
 object                      ( x,y,z )
 position 1
```

I want rotate object according to fix point (x,y,z) with Q angle. With opengl, how can I do that ?

Object goes from position 1 to position 2 .

I know Q, (x,y,z).

I have done :

```
glPushMAtrix ()
glTranslatef ( -x, -y, -z ) ;
glRotatef ( Q, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

glCylinder ( /*argument*/ ) 
glPopMatriX ()
```

Comment: Rotation around a point is not well defined. Do Object 1, Object 2 and point Y define a plane/normal?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I do not understand, please be clear

Answer (score 1):

If you are rotating in 3D space and know only object, angle and the center of rotation, then your task is undefined. In 3D space you can rotate only around some axis, not point.

From your code example you are rotating around X axis. Let me guess that's what you really want.

To achieve this you should translte orign of coordinate system to the center of rotation, perform rotation and translate coordinate system back.

```
glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
glRotatef(Q, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
// draw the object
```

If you know the initial and final position of your object, then you can calculate the axis of rotation. (Since 3 points always define a plane and its normal.) In vector notation it should look this way (May be wrong in axis direction. If object rotates on opposite direction change the sign of axis or angle).

```
axis = vec(center_of_rotation - initial_position, center_of_rotation - final_position)
```

Or a little bit more "for dummies"

```
float X1[3]; // initial position
float X2[3]; // final position
float O[3]; // orign of rotation

float OX1[3]; OX1[0] = X1[0] - O[0]; OX1[1] = X1[1] - O[1]; OX1[2] = X1[2] - O[2];
float OX2[3]; OX2[0] = X2[0] - O[0]; OX2[1] = X2[1] - O[1]; OX2[2] = X2[2] - O[2];

float axis[3]; // vector product OX1 and OX2
axis[0] = OX1[1]*OX2[2]-OX1[2]*OX2[1];
axis[1] = OX1[2]*OX2[0]-OX1[0]*OX2[2];
axis[2] = OX1[0]*OX2[1]-OX1[1]*OX2[0];
```

Comment: Can you explain axis a bit more ? I am rotating in 3d environment .

Comment: You can't rotate just around a point. To make task defined you should define axis. For example you have point at (1,0,0) and want to rotate it 90 degrees around orign (0,0,0). You can do it around Z axis (0,0,1) and get point with coordinates (0,1,0). Or you can rotate it around Y axis and get (0,0,-1). OR you can even rotate around X axis and get the same point (1,0,0).

Comment: What should I do ? Should I first calculate axis then according to them, rotate the object

Comment: Exactly. But don't forget to translate orign of coordinates to (and from) center of rotation

Comment: you say first calculate axis then does first translate acc to -x,-y,-z then rotate Q, axis[0],axis[1],axis[2] then translate back

Comment: Normalizing axis won't hurt.

Comment: Using new OpenGL won't hurt, either.